# Ubuntu 11.10 not starting in Graphical mode?

Tags: graphics, restart

I am in deep trouble. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 in dual boot mode with XP.

Originally my touch pad was not working, (sometimes). To fix that, I installed something. After reboot my Ubuntu is not booting up!!

I have several software pkgs already installed in past several weeks so reinstall of OS is my last resort. Can someone help me to get it rebooted in graphical mode?

I had followed the [procedure mentioned in this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860135) as well. With that link, somehow I am able to restart in text mode. But no luck after that. I am not being able to go back on graphical mode.

The important outputs of `lspci` are following:

```
00.00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
```

I am attaching few snapshots, for more details on hardware.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @fossfreedom, thanks, But I after I chosen "Recover mode", I see 4 options as, `resume`, `fsck`, `remount`, `root`. Sorry for my ignorance, if I don't know much as I am novice in Ubuntu shifted from XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after lot of struggling, I was able to resolve this issue. And I happily writing this answer from the same Ubuntu which I lost for few hours.

If the Ubuntu is not booting up, then when the blank screen appears press `Ctrl + Alt + (F1 to F6, anything)` or goto recover mode to check from the command line.

Then, I checked following file:

```
sudo vi /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

It will give you the information, where exactly you are failing. For example, it was failing for me in one of the files which I wrongly edited. See the bold text below.

```
[    16.685] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
[    16.685] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.685] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server i686 Ubuntu
[    16.685] Current Operating System: Linux Ubuntu11.10 3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 13:25:36 UTC 2011 i686
[    16.685] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=0e1d28e3-b3cc-4022-81c6-4f4d24ac6f63 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    16.685] Build Date: 19 October 2011  05:09:41AM
[    16.685] xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    16.685] Current version of pixman: 0.22.2
[    16.685]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    16.685] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    16.685] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov 26 22:59:34 2011
[    16.865] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

**

> [    17.051] Parse error on line 14 of section InputClass in file
>   /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
>           "ppa:sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads" is not a valid keyword in this section. [    17.051] (EE) Problem parsing the config file [
>   17.051] (EE) Error parsing the config file [    17.051]  Fatal server error: [    17.051] no screens found [    17.051]  Please consult the
>   The X.Org Foundation support

**

I simply removed that line and rebooted. It again appeared with blank screen, I just tried randomly other `tty` section (e.g. `tty2`), by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F2` and I to my pleasant surprise I saw the **graphical login screen**!!!

I just checked if everything is intact. Also, due to upgrade, I see small changes in usability, but rest is fine otherwise. This is my first successful login after that disaster and I hope that it will continue without any problem in future.

Lesson, I learned were, to fix a small problem don't do unnecessary upgrade/updates and screw your time and energy. Thanks.

Comment: @iammilind - well done, you should accept your own answer too as it solved your problem.